# How to specify correct url to .xap file in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement my Silverlight app in my MVC Project.
I added .xap file to some folder in my MVC Projcet
On my page I add the next x-silverlight element:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
            <param name="source" value="ClientBin/AudioRecorder.xap" />
            <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
            <param name="background" value="white" />
            <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.41108.0" />
            <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
            <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.41108.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" />
            </a>
        </object>
        <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px; border: 0px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Here I specify source of .xap file

```
<param name="source" value="ClientBin/AudioRecorder.xap" />
```

ClientBin locates in root folder of my MVC App, but when I check `Network` in firebug, I see that request is:

```
http://localhost:61244/Home/ClientBin/AudioRecorder.xap
```

It's contain `Home/` and of course I'm getting 404 error (File not found)
How to fix this to get this file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the absolute path - Add "/" to make it absolute!

```
<param name="source" value="/ClientBin/AudioRecorder.xap" />
```